# cd rom copy How can I copy music direcly to my computer and not a cd

Tags: 13.10

How can I copy a cd into my computer? I tried extract juicer but it doesnt have the mp3 option and when i choose another it brings the cd but when i put extract it doesn't do it. how can I do this, is it posible in ubuntu as in windows. or itunes to just extract tracks directly into your computer without having to burn a cd? thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To convert your CD-AUDIO discs to MP3 with Rhythmbox or Sound Juicer, you will need to install either `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly` or `gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly`, depending on which version of the GStreamer API the app is using, to be able to have the MP3 option for encoding appear and work when configuring Rhythmbox or Sound Juicer.

Answer (score 0):

You might try *abcde*. From *man abcde*:

```
abcde  -  Grab  an  entire CD and compress it to Ogg/Vorbis, MP3, FLAC,
Ogg/Speex and/or MPP/MP+(Musepack) format.
```

Put the CD in the tray. Open a terminal. Change directories to your preferred directory. Rip to mp3 automagically:

```
sudo apt-get install abcde
cd ~/Music
abcde -o mp3
```