# How to "Rip" music with 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, music, cd-ripping

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS.

I have a music CD that I wanted to add to my hard drive and I cannot find a tool to convert / "RIP" the music.

Sound Juicer is recommended and considered the "official" tool, however it is not available from the software catalog.

Searching for help on this finds results one year or older.

Has this functionality been removed or omitted for some reason?

Thank you,

David.In.Tucson

Comment: Sound Juicer is there according to https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?sound-juicer, for all supported releases.  It's found in 'universe' so have you enabled 'Universe' in your software-sources?  (*its not been removed; I think its less used as lots of people stream their music*)

Comment: I've been using [Asunder](http://littlesvr.ca/asunder/). It's slow but it works. You can install it with `sudo apt install asunder`.

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/407067/cd-rom-copy-how-can-i-copy-music-direcly-to-my-computer-and-not-a-cd/407082#407082

Answer (score 0):

It's there on 16.04.3 LTS:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS \n \l 
$ apt search sound-juicer
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
sound-juicer/xenial 3.18.1-1 amd64
  GNOME CD Ripper
```

I prefer a cli tool like `cdparanoia`, but I'm old-fashioned that way :)